# How to determine encoding of following HTML tag

Tags: python, html, utf-8

Is there a way to figure out the encoding of the following `meta` description?

```
<meta content="Handyman John Garfield&amp;#39;s torrid affair with married Lana Turner leads to the murder of her husband and a tragic betrayal. MPAA Rating: NOTRATED  (c) 1946 A Warner Bros. Entertainment Inc. All Rights Reserved" itemprop="description">
```

How would I (1) Figure out the encoding of the above and (2) Encode this into UTF, so it reads as below

`Handyman John Garfield's torrid affair with married Lana Turner leads to the murder of her husband and a tragic betrayal. MPAA Rating: NOTRATED  (c) 1946 A Warner Bros. Entertainment Inc. All Rights Reserved`

Comment: I’m not exactly sure how you intend to use the encoding or what encoding related difficulties you run into; but you can always try adding a `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`…

Comment: This is not my HTML, I'm grabbing it from another website's webpage. I cannot modify it.

Comment: Well, okay, this looks as if it’s already in UTF-8, but it’s got a “doubled” HTML entity `&amp;#39;` where you’d need to convert `&amp;` into `&` and finally `&#39;` into `'`. 39 is basically the decimal Unicode code point for the apostrophe.